# Yandex API Translator not working on Android Aplication

Tags: yandex

I'm trying to use the Yandex translator in my Android application, but it is giving an error. When tested in a Java application (in the main), it works perfectly. What is my problem?

Main code:

```
import com.rmtheis.yandtran.language.Language;
import com.rmtheis.yandtran.translate.Translate;
import com.veryinteligent.jarvas.R;

import com.veryinteligent.jarvas.activity.WordCommands;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class YandexTranslator extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.wordcommands);
        Translate.setKey(WordCommands.myKey);
        String term = "obrigado por me ajudar";
        try {
            term = Translate.execute(term, Language.PORTUGUESE, Language.ENGLISH);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(term);
    }
}  

import com.rmtheis.yandtran.language.Language;
import com.rmtheis.yandtran.translate.Translate;

public class TranslationTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Translate.setKey("trnsl.1.1.20160515T173032Z.cb8002677c95725e.93f4f996a1647d5d0c6e336758723a8bb1bb41b4");

        String term = "abrir vá";
        try {
            term = Translate.execute(term, Language.PORTUGUESE, Language.ENGLISH);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(term);

    }

}
```

Error:

```
08-11 16:10:35.333: I/dalvikvm(1152): Could not find method org.json.simple.JSONValue.parse, referenced from method com.rmtheis.yandtran.YandexTranslatorAPI.jsonObjValToStringArr
08-11 16:10:35.333: W/dalvikvm(1152): VFY: unable to resolve static method 15804: Lorg/json/simple/JSONValue;.parse (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;
08-11 16:10:35.333: D/dalvikvm(1152): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0000
08-11 16:10:35.333: D/dalvikvm(1152): VFY: dead code 0x0003-0015 in Lcom/rmtheis/yandtran/YandexTranslatorAPI;.jsonObjValToStringArr (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)[Ljava/lang/String;
08-11 16:10:35.333: I/dalvikvm(1152): Could not find method org.json.simple.JSONValue.parse, referenced from method com.rmtheis.yandtran.YandexTranslatorAPI.retrievePropString
08-11 16:10:35.333: W/dalvikvm(1152): VFY: unable to resolve static method 15804: Lorg/json/simple/JSONValue;.parse (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;
08-11 16:10:35.333: D/dalvikvm(1152): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0004
08-11 16:10:35.333: D/dalvikvm(1152): VFY: dead code 0x0007-0012 in Lcom/rmtheis/yandtran/YandexTranslatorAPI;.retrievePropString (Ljava/net/URL;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
08-11 16:10:35.333: W/System.err(1152): java.net.UnknownHostException: translate.yandex.net
08-11 16:10:35.333: W/System.err(1152):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:497)
08-11 16:10:35.333: W/System.err(1152):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:294)
08-11 16:10:35.333: W/System.err(1152):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:256)
08-11 16:10:35.333: W/System.err(1152):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:69)
08-11 16:10:35.333: W/System.err(1152):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:48)
08-11 16:10:35.333: W/System.err(1152):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:322)
08-11 16:10:35.333: W/System.err(1152):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:89)
08-11 16:10:35.333: W/System.err(1152):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHttpConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:285)
08-11 16:10:35.333: W/System.err(1152):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.makeConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:267)
08-11 16:10:35.333: W/System.err(1152):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:406)
08-11 16:10:35.333: W/System.err(1152):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:387)
08-11 16:10:35.333: W/System.err(1152):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.retrieveResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1018)
08-11 16:10:35.333: W/System.err(1152):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:726)
08-11 16:10:35.333: W/System.err(1152):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:121)
08-11 16:10:35.333: W/System.err(1152):     at com.rmtheis.yandtran.YandexTranslatorAPI.retrieveResponse(YandexTranslatorAPI.java:76)
08-11 16:10:35.333: W/System.err(1152):     at com.rmtheis.yandtran.YandexTranslatorAPI.retrievePropArrString(YandexTranslatorAPI.java:104)
08-11 16:10:35.333: W/System.err(1152):     at com.rmtheis.yandtran.translate.Translate.execute(Translate.java:52)
08-11 16:10:35.333: W/System.err(1152):     at com.veryinteligent.jarvas.activity.YandexTranslator.onCreate(YandexTranslator.java:22)
08-11 16:10:35.333: W/System.err(1152):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-11 16:10:35.333: W/System.err(1152):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
08-11 16:10:35.333: W/System.err(1152):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
08-11 16:10:35.333: W/System.err(1152):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-11 16:10:35.333: W/System.err(1152):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
08-11 16:10:35.333: W/System.err(1152):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-11 16:10:35.333: W/System.err(1152):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-11 16:10:35.333: W/System.err(1152):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-11 16:10:35.333: W/System.err(1152):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-11 16:10:35.333: W/System.err(1152):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-11 16:10:35.333: W/System.err(1152):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-11 16:10:35.333: W/System.err(1152):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-11 16:10:35.333: W/System.err(1152):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-11 16:10:35.333: I/System.out(1152):
```

Comment: Improved formatting of error message; fixed some wording.

Comment: Thank you. I'm still a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

I use this code [here](https://github.com/rmtheis/yandex-translator-java-api) and it works fine for me

1: add json_simple-1.1.jar to your project [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fHEvI_G6UtI)

2: copy classes code from `yandex-translator-java-api/src/com/rmtheis/yandtran/` to your project

3: Put your API key in `ApiKeys.java`

4: put this lines to translate a text:

```
    Translate.setKey(ApiKeys.YANDEX_API_KEY);

    String translatedText = Translate.execute("Hola, mundo!", Language.SPANISH, Language.ENGLISH);
```

5: if you get `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` error that's because this exception is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread, **Solution**:

-- Add this lines in your `YandexTranslatorApi.java`

```
static class RetrieveResponse extends AsyncTask<URL,Void,String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(URL... params) {
            String result = "";
            try {
                result = retrieveResponse(params[0]);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

-- in `retrievePropString` and `retrievePropArrString` method change this line:

```
final String response = retrieveResponse(url);
```

by this:

```
final String response = new RetrieveResponse().execute(url).get();
```

**Edited:**
add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` to your `AndroidManifest.xml`
Good luck ^_^